# Haskell test different implementations of mapM

Tags: haskell, monads

I have implemented sequence' :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a] below

```
sequence' [] = return []
sequence' (m : ms)
  = m >>=
      \ a ->
        do as <- sequence' ms
           return (a : as)
```

I need to test following implementations of 
mapM' :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]

```
mapM'a f as = sequence' (map f as)

mapM'b f [] = return []
mapM'b f (a : as)
  = f a >>= \b -> mapM'b f as >>= \ bs -> return (b : bs)

mapM'f f [] = return []
mapM'f f (a : as) =
    do b <- f a
       bs <- mapM'f f as
       return (b : bs)

mapM'g f [] = return []
mapM'g f (a : as)
  = f a >>=
      \ b ->
        do bs <- mapM'g f as
           return (b : bs)

mapM'h f [] = return []
mapM'h f (a : as)
  = f a >>=
      \ b ->
      do bs <- mapM'h f as
         return (bs ++ [b])
```

Please let me know how do I test and verify above implementations of mapM - which functions I should call.
Some examples will be very useful.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like your teacher is trying to get you used to the way `do` notation translates into applications of `>>=`. Try running a simple function like `\x -> Just (x + 1)` and a test list like `[1,2,3]` through your various `mapM` functions and look at the outputs. (Hint: one of the implementations is incorrect!)

Answer (score 1):

One class of monads you may find useful in your testing are the [*free monads*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html) over various functors. Free monads tend to be particularly sensitive to any mistakes you may make in your implementation. You can use any reasonably flexible base functor, such as `[]`, for your tests.

```
data Free f a = Pure a
              | Free (f (Free f a))

instance Functor f => Functor (Free f) where
  fmap f (Pure a) = Pure (f a)
  fmap f (Free xs) = Free (fmap (fmap f) xs)

instance Functor f => Applicative (Free f) where
  pure = Pure
  (<*>) = ap

instance Functor f => Monad (Free f) where
  Pure x >>= f = f x
  Free xs >>= f = Free (fmap (>>= f) xs)

instance (Eq (f (Free f a)), Eq a) => Eq (Free f a) where
  Pure a == Pure b = a == b
  Free fa == Free fb = fa == fb
  _ == _ = False
```